# Run a script (or set stringsAsFactors = FALSE) while loading a package in R

Tags: r, package

I previously used `Rprofile.site` to set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. However, numerous sources state using `Rprofile.site` for this purpose makes code less portable. My solution has been to run `source('C:/...startup.script.R')` every time I load R. This startup script sets `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (along with accomplishing other tasks). This works, but in order to share my scripts with others I would have to share the script of interest and my `startup.script.R` script.

I am creating a custom package that will allow me to share my custom functions. I plan to put `require(MyCustomFunctionsPackage)` (or something to that effect) at the beginning of all of my scripts in order to load my custom functions. I want to embed `source('C:/...startup.script.R')` (or something to that effect) and the `startup.script.R` file in the `MyCustomFunctionsPackage` package such that, when I share my scripts, I will only need to share the script of interest with a call to `devtools::install_github('MyCustomFunctionsPackage','github_username')` and all of my custom functions and settings will be loaded. Is there a way to do this? I'm sure the answer is in [Hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) or the [CRAN literature](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html) somewhere, but I'm not sure what keywords to search.

Comment: Perhaps opinions on this will differ, but I would not want a package that I load to alter my `stringsAsFactors` session option. If a package exhibited that sort of behavior I would not use it. If you want your code to avoid dealing with factors, it is probably best to handle it manually in your internal code.

Comment: Point well taken. I should probably just deal with including `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` in any script that needs this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply a function named [`.onLoad()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-hooks.html) that will be called whenever the package is loaded. Here's a simple reproducible example showing how it can be used:

```
## Create and install a package containing a function `.onLoad()`
library(pkgKitten)
kitten("myopts")
cat(
".onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname) {
    options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
", file = "myopts/R/zzz.R")

devtools::install("myopts")

## Confirm that loading the package sets stringsAsFactors
options('stringsAsFactors')
## $stringsAsFactors
## [1] TRUE

library(myopts)
options('stringsAsFactors')
## $stringsAsFactors
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Upvoted `pkgKitten` in the wild!  :)  Also shows the `options()` approach rendering the question moot for this particular setting.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hah! TBH, I answered mostly to demonstrate just how easily one can make a package with `kitten()` to try out some code/an idea. But looks like I was just preaching to the preacher ;)